# select multiple options at a time

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

```
   <select class="form-control default-select2 " id="group" data-size="10" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-white" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Group</option>
    <!-- <option value="1">Admin</option>
                                        <option value="4">User</option> -->
        <?php $groups = $objUser->GetGroups(); ?> 
         <?php   foreach($groups as $group){ ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $group['id'] ?>"<?php echo ($data[0]['group_id'] == $group['id'] ? "selected='selected'" : "") ?>><?php echo $group['primary_name'] ?></option> <? } ?>
</select>
```

Now I want user to select multiple option at a time. i searched the whole internet but i couldn't find the answer to fix this issue. i dont know what i am missing.

Comment: You have `multiple="multiple"` attribute in the `<select>` so are you sure you know how to select more than one item in a dropdown? You hold the CTRL Key down as you make the selections

Comment: if you were talking about the selected values that will be submitted to PHP, you will need to define a name for the select menu;

Comment: You dont actually explain what your issue is. It will help someone provide an answer if you make the specific issue very obvious

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually comman user don't about the ctrl + clicking. that's why i wanna that is there any for user to select multiple option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can actually manage multiple selections. Just hold Ctrl key and click on different options.
Exemple of multiple select : [here](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_select_multiple.asp)

When you submit the form, you will be able to get all the selected options into an array.

Comment: I was wondering if I should make an answer out of my comment, but now you have saved me the effort

Comment: As u said, we have no much detail about the real problem. So, for now, I think it is the most helpful answer we can give. I saw your answer too late, and I was wondering if I had to make it an answer as well :D

Comment: @shabang yes it is very very helpful answer. according  to your given link think i have to uses checkboxes instead of select element. becs my this define code does not work.

Comment: @shabang   can i get this functionality with bootstrap class.?

Comment: @stackOverFlowGeek yes, look at right [here](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#multiple-select-boxes) ;) With that bootstrap class, you don't need to bother anymore with the Ctrl holding trick.